# Feature move animation in OpenLayers 3.11.2

Tags: openlayers

I'm looking for a way to re-use the technique underneath this OpenLayers example but I don't really understand its structure, especially this part:

```
// This long string is placed here due to jsFiddle limitations.
// It is usually loaded with AJAX.
var polyline = [
'hldhx@lnau`BCG_EaC??cFjAwDjF??uBlKMd@}@z@??aC^yk@z_@se@b[wFdE??wFfE}N',
'fIoGxB_I\\gG}@eHoCyTmPqGaBaHOoD\\??yVrGotA|N??o[N_STiwAtEmHGeHcAkiA}^',
'aMyBiHOkFNoI`CcVvM??gG^gF_@iJwC??eCcA]OoL}DwFyCaCgCcCwDcGwHsSoX??wI_E',
'kUFmq@hBiOqBgTwS??iYse@gYq\\cp@ce@{vA}s@csJqaE}{@iRaqE{lBeRoIwd@_T{]_',
'Ngn@{PmhEwaA{SeF_u@kQuyAw]wQeEgtAsZ}LiCarAkVwI}D??_}RcjEinPspDwSqCgs@',
'sPua@_OkXaMeT_Nwk@ob@gV}TiYs[uTwXoNmT{Uyb@wNg]{Nqa@oDgNeJu_@_G}YsFw]k',
'DuZyDmm@i_@uyIJe~@jCg|@nGiv@zUi_BfNqaAvIow@dEed@dCcf@r@qz@Egs@{Acu@mC',
'um@yIey@gGig@cK_m@aSku@qRil@we@{mAeTej@}Tkz@cLgr@aHko@qOmcEaJw~C{w@ka',
'i@qBchBq@kmBS{kDnBscBnFu_Dbc@_~QHeU`IuyDrC_}@bByp@fCyoA?qMbD}{AIkeAgB',
'k_A_A{UsDke@gFej@qH{o@qGgb@qH{`@mMgm@uQus@kL{_@yOmd@ymBgwE}x@ouBwtA__',
'DuhEgaKuWct@gp@cnBii@mlBa_@}|Asj@qrCg^eaC}L{dAaJ_aAiOyjByH{nAuYu`GsAw',
'Xyn@ywMyOyqD{_@cfIcDe}@y@aeBJmwA`CkiAbFkhBlTgdDdPyiB`W}xDnSa}DbJyhCrX',
'itAhT}x@bE}Z_@qW_Kwv@qKaaAiBgXvIm}A~JovAxCqW~WanB`XewBbK{_A`K}fBvAmi@',
'xBycBeCauBoF}}@qJioAww@gjHaPopA_NurAyJku@uGmi@cDs[eRaiBkQstAsQkcByNma',
'CsK_uBcJgbEw@gkB_@ypEqDoqSm@eZcDwjBoGw`BoMegBaU_`Ce_@_uBqb@ytBwkFqiT_',
'fAqfEwe@mfCka@_eC_UmlB}MmaBeWkkDeHwqAoX}~DcBsZmLcxBqOwqE_DkyAuJmrJ\\o',
'~CfIewG|YibQxBssB?es@qGciA}RorAoVajA_nAodD{[y`AgPqp@mKwr@ms@umEaW{dAm',
'b@umAw|@ojBwzDaaJsmBwbEgdCsrFqhAihDquAi`Fux@}_Dui@_eB_u@guCuyAuiHukA_',
'lKszAu|OmaA{wKm}@clHs_A_rEahCssKo\\sgBsSglAqk@yvDcS_wAyTwpBmPc|BwZknF',
'oFscB_GsaDiZmyMyLgtHgQonHqT{hKaPg}Dqq@m~Hym@c`EuiBudIabB{hF{pWifx@snA',
'w`GkFyVqf@y~BkoAi}Lel@wtc@}`@oaXi_C}pZsi@eqGsSuqJ|Lqeb@e]kgPcaAu}SkDw',
'zGhn@gjYh\\qlNZovJieBqja@ed@siO{[ol\\kCmjMe\\isHorCmec@uLebB}EqiBaCg}',
'@m@qwHrT_vFps@kkI`uAszIrpHuzYxx@e{Crw@kpDhN{wBtQarDy@knFgP_yCu\\wyCwy',
'A{kHo~@omEoYmoDaEcPiuAosDagD}rO{{AsyEihCayFilLaiUqm@_bAumFo}DgqA_uByi',
'@swC~AkzDlhA}xEvcBa}Cxk@ql@`rAo|@~bBq{@``Bye@djDww@z_C_cAtn@ye@nfC_eC',
'|gGahH~s@w}@``Fi~FpnAooC|u@wlEaEedRlYkrPvKerBfYs}Arg@m}AtrCkzElw@gjBb',
'h@woBhR{gCwGkgCc[wtCuOapAcFoh@uBy[yBgr@c@iq@o@wvEv@sp@`FajBfCaq@fIipA',
'dy@ewJlUc`ExGuaBdEmbBpBssArAuqBBg}@s@g{AkB{bBif@_bYmC}r@kDgm@sPq_BuJ_',
's@{X_{AsK_d@eM{d@wVgx@oWcu@??aDmOkNia@wFoSmDyMyCkPiBePwAob@XcQ|@oNdCo',
'SfFwXhEmOnLi\\lbAulB`X_d@|k@au@bc@oc@bqC}{BhwDgcD`l@ed@??bL{G|a@eTje@',
'oS~]cLr~Bgh@|b@}Jv}EieAlv@sPluD{z@nzA_]`|KchCtd@sPvb@wSb{@ko@f`RooQ~e',
'[upZbuIolI|gFafFzu@iq@nMmJ|OeJn^{Qjh@yQhc@uJ~j@iGdd@kAp~BkBxO{@|QsAfY',
'gEtYiGd]}Jpd@wRhVoNzNeK`j@ce@vgK}cJnSoSzQkVvUm^rSgc@`Uql@xIq\\vIgg@~k',
'Dyq[nIir@jNoq@xNwc@fYik@tk@su@neB}uBhqEesFjoGeyHtCoD|D}Ed|@ctAbIuOzqB',
'_}D~NgY`\\um@v[gm@v{Cw`G`w@o{AdjAwzBh{C}`Gpp@ypAxn@}mAfz@{bBbNia@??jI',
'ab@`CuOlC}YnAcV`@_^m@aeB}@yk@YuTuBg^uCkZiGk\\yGeY}Lu_@oOsZiTe[uWi[sl@',
'mo@soAauAsrBgzBqgAglAyd@ig@asAcyAklA}qAwHkGi{@s~@goAmsAyDeEirB_{B}IsJ',
'uEeFymAssAkdAmhAyTcVkFeEoKiH}l@kp@wg@sj@ku@ey@uh@kj@}EsFmG}Jk^_r@_f@m',
'~@ym@yjA??a@cFd@kBrCgDbAUnAcBhAyAdk@et@??kF}D??OL'
].join('');
```

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.2/examples/feature-move-animation.html

- How can I put my own data into the polyline variable?
- How could I use directly a GeoJSON or a KML file to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data in the polyline variable is in the Encoded Polyline format.  Google has a utility you can use to prepare test data in this format ([link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility?hl=en)).

You can convert your own data to this format using PostGIS and the ST_AsEncodedPolyline function ([docs](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_LineFromEncodedPolyline.html)).

Or you could use any of the other formats supported by OpenLayers 3.  Just swap out `new ol.format.Polyline` as appropriate.